# Adobe InDesign CS6: Multiple spaces in HTML export

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, html

Is there a way to preserve multiple spaces in HTML export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following workaround now:

Search two times for all occurances of `(  |~S )` and replace it with `~S~S` (GREP).

The resulting non-breaking spaces are exported correctly.

Comment: For correcting line breaks in my case it makes sense to replace `~b` with `\n` too,